# Can't reindex from web admin

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex, indexing

I can't reindex **catalog_category_flat** index from web admin, I see an error message. But I **can** reindex it from the console by running

> php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat

without a problem. What could be the problem?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this - http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/cannot-initialize-the-indexer-process-in-index-management-in-magento/

**Take backup of database before running the SQL query**

Answer (score 0):

Generally this problem due to `max_execution_time`.

Just increase `max_execution_time` according to your server setting.
Two way to do so

1) php.ini (must be in root directory)

```
max_execution_time = 18000
```

2) .htaccess (must be in root directory)

```
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

Thank you.